# How to limit the product order if it exceeds the amount woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm stucked in an issue. I want to limit the product order if it exceeds the amount in woocommerce.
Like "Limit 5 per order" on any specific product over $20

Comment: you want user only select 5 quantity in single product

Comment: yes, but need to check if that product increases the price($20) then the customer can buy only 5 products. Suppose the product price is $2, then customer can buy 10 products and on the other hand if the product price is $20 then need to restrict the purchase limit that the customer can buy only 5 product.

Comment: I did these thing, with https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-max-quantity/ plugin. you use this

Comment: or this will help to check price with quantity https://wordpress.org/plugins/min-and-max-purchase-for-woocommerce/

Comment: @Mollie thanks for this information. I really appreciate. But I think these plugins doesn't meet my requirement. Can you please read my above comment again.? where I have explained about my query

Comment: i read these but need to try Min and Max Purchase for WooCommerce plugin

Comment: @mollie it's not working according to my requirement.. Is there any another method that you know?